# Insert color for each Row Grouping jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use API methods to perform row grouping

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5jccbzdy/2/

```
// DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, 'asc']],
        "drawCallback": function (settings){
            var api = this.api();

            // Zero-based index of the column containing names
            var col_name = 0;

            // If ordered by column containing names
            if (api.order()[0][0] === col_name) {
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var group_last = null;

                api.column(col_name, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (name, index){
                    var group = name;

                    if (group_last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(index).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );

                        group_last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I want insert color for each row grouping by "css" column (You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5jccbzdy/2/. Column 5th). So, giving color to row grouping by css column. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert following code inside DataTable function

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                $('td', row).eq(4).addClass('highlight');
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jccbzdy/6/

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have a little problem. I try like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5jccbzdy/7/. But failed. I did not succeed coloring row grouping.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to all of column is colored ,this process is done in `drawcallback` function .The corrected version of the code is following.     http://jsfiddle.net/5jccbzdy/8/

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. But, I just want color the rows grouped. I want make it like this : http://postimg.org/image/dtug5xlez/. So, the column are colored only the column that are grouped